# How to write local orc file using Presto

Tags: presto, orc, trino

How to write file of result CTAS(crate table as) using localfile connector and orc file format with presto

example query :

```
 CREATE TABLE localfile.default.lineitem_orc_parted with (
  format = 'ORC',
  partitioned_by = ARRAY['commityear'],
  bucketed_by = ARRAY['linenumber'],
  bucket_count = 7
) AS SELECT *,year(commitdate) as commityear from tcph.sf100.lineitem limit 100000000;
```

--> *Catalog 'localfile' does not support table property 'format'*

Is it possible with/without partitoning,bucketing?

Answer (score 1):

The [Presto `localfile` connector](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/localfile.html) currently supports reading from `http-request.log` only. It does not allow reading ORC files, nor creating any tables. There is no builtin connector really suitable for dumping ORC files out of Presto.

As a workaround, I would suggest using [Presto Hive connector](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html) and writing (CTAS) to a table. Then you just copy the file from table's location.

If this doesn't satisfy your needs, I suggest you create an issue: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues and join the conversation on [Presto Slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html).

Comment: yeah it can be with hive connector but my purpose comparing remote hive+orc and localstorage+orc. According to i understand , it is not possible now.  Localfile connector doesnt support create table , ctas , orc file etc.. only http-request.log table reading.